# How to add custom attributes and properties on <stencil-route-link> router link?

Tags: html, routes, accessibility, stenciljs

I am trying to create the Navigation component. I need to add some attributes/custom-attributes on Navigation links. I am able to add some of them, like follows.

- url="/"
- anchorClass="menu active"
- anchorRole="menuitem"
- anchorTabIndex="2"
- anchorTitle="Menu Title"

There are some more attributes I required to add on links, but I am not able to add these attributes on link, as follows.

- **aria-haspopup="true"**
- **id="consumers"**
- **aria-posinset="1"**
- **aria-setsize="2"**
- **aria-label="Home menu"**

I am trying to add the attributes on `<stencil-route-link>` as follows .

```
<stencil-route-link anchorClass="some classes" url="/" anchorClass="menu active" anchorRole="menuitem" anchorTabIndex="2" anchorTitle="Menu Title" anchorAriaHaspopup="true" anchorId="consumers" anchorAriaPosinset="1" anchorAriaSetsize="2" anchorAriaLabel="Home menu">Home</stencil-route-link>
```

Please help.

Comment: Keep in mind that your ARIA usage should be kept to a minimum and to use native html when possible.  See the "First Rule of ARIA Use" (https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#rule1).  I mention this because you said you want to add `aria-setsize` and `aria-posinset`.  Those attributes should only be used **if** you can't use a native list (`<ol>` or `<ul>`).  I'm not familiar with stencil but if it has a list construct, you should use it rather than these aria attributes.  Now, as far as how to inject these attributes into stencil, I'll have to leave that to someone that knows stencil.

Answer (score 1):

You could navigate manually instead of using `<stencil-route-link>`. This way you have complete control over the HTML.

```
import { RouterHistory } from '@stencil/router';

export class SomeRoutedPage {
 @Prop() history: RouterHistory;

  render() {
    return (<a onClick={() => this.history.push('/')} data-custom-attribute="test">Home</a>
  }
}
```

Here's a link to [the relevant docs](https://stenciljs.com/docs/router/#navigating-programmatically).

I'm not quite sure how exactly the `href` attribute is generated but you could get that from [the `<stencil-route-link>` source](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-router/blob/master/packages/router/src/components/route-link/route-link.tsx).

Alternatively you could extend that component to allow for arbitrary attributes and send a pull request.